# indexPathForRowAtPoint always return 0

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'd like to get indexPath at the given point.
In spite of scrolling tableView, myIndexPath.row always return 0.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    myIndexPath = [myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:self.view.center];
}
```

How do I fix it to get indexPath?

Comment: The coordinate system you are using is in terms of view's superview's coordinate system. Convert it to table view and  use the same method as above.

Comment: You can use [myTableView convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superView]